# Python group by without Pandas' proprietary GroupBy

Tags: python, list, dictionary, group-by

I have an output like this:

```
{((0, 0), 'up'): 'v_1_0',
 ((0, 0), 'down'): 'v_0_0',
 ((0, 0), 'left'): 'v_0_0',
 ((0, 0), 'right'): 'v_0_1',
 ((0, 1), 'up'): 'v_1_1',
 ((0, 1), 'down'): 'v_0_1',
 ((0, 1), 'left'): 'v_0_0',
 ((0, 1), 'right'): 'v_0_2',
 ((0, 2), 'up'): 'v_1_2',
 ((0, 2), 'down'): 'v_0_2',
 ((0, 2), 'left'): 'v_0_1',
 ((0, 2), 'right'): 'v_0_3',
 ((0, 3), 'up'): 'v_1_3',
 ((0, 3), 'down'): 'v_0_3',
 ((0, 3), 'left'): 'v_0_2',
 ((0, 3), 'right'): 'v_0_3',
.
.
.
.
```

I'd like to arrange it like this:

```
{(0, 0): ['v_1_0', 'v_0_0', 'v_0_0', 'v_0_1'],
(0, 1): ['v_1_1', 'v_0_1', 'v_0_0', 'v_0_2'],
.
.
```

So, basically, discard the 'up', 'down', 'left', and 'right' parts, and club the `values` into an array by their `keys`.

I know I can use Pandas' GroupBy to do this but I'd like to avoid an extra module import if I can.

I've tried approaching it in different ways but nothing has worked. Any help is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
dct = {
    ((0, 0), "up"): "v_1_0",
    ((0, 0), "down"): "v_0_0",
    ((0, 0), "left"): "v_0_0",
    ((0, 0), "right"): "v_0_1",
    ((0, 1), "up"): "v_1_1",
    ((0, 1), "down"): "v_0_1",
    ((0, 1), "left"): "v_0_0",
    ((0, 1), "right"): "v_0_2",
    ((0, 2), "up"): "v_1_2",
    ((0, 2), "down"): "v_0_2",
    ((0, 2), "left"): "v_0_1",
    ((0, 2), "right"): "v_0_3",
    ((0, 3), "up"): "v_1_3",
    ((0, 3), "down"): "v_0_3",
    ((0, 3), "left"): "v_0_2",
    ((0, 3), "right"): "v_0_3",
}

out = {}
for (t, _), v in dct.items():
    out.setdefault(t, []).append(v)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    (0, 0): ["v_1_0", "v_0_0", "v_0_0", "v_0_1"],
    (0, 1): ["v_1_1", "v_0_1", "v_0_0", "v_0_2"],
    (0, 2): ["v_1_2", "v_0_2", "v_0_1", "v_0_3"],
    (0, 3): ["v_1_3", "v_0_3", "v_0_2", "v_0_3"],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) standard library:

```
itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None)
```

> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each element. If not specified or is None, key defaults to an identity function and returns the element unchanged. Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> dct = {((0, 0), 'up'): 'v_1_0',
...  ((0, 0), 'down'): 'v_0_0',
...  ((0, 0), 'left'): 'v_0_0',
...  ((0, 0), 'right'): 'v_0_1',
...  ((0, 1), 'up'): 'v_1_1',
...  ((0, 1), 'down'): 'v_0_1',
...  ((0, 1), 'left'): 'v_0_0',
...  ((0, 1), 'right'): 'v_0_2',
...  ((0, 2), 'up'): 'v_1_2',
...  ((0, 2), 'down'): 'v_0_2',
...  ((0, 2), 'left'): 'v_0_1',
...  ((0, 2), 'right'): 'v_0_3',
...  ((0, 3), 'up'): 'v_1_3',
...  ((0, 3), 'down'): 'v_0_3',
...  ((0, 3), 'left'): 'v_0_2',
...  ((0, 3), 'right'): 'v_0_3',
...
... }
>>> pprint({l:[x[1] for x in group] for l,group in groupby(dct.items(),key=lambda x:x[0][0])})
{(0, 0): ['v_1_0', 'v_0_0', 'v_0_0', 'v_0_1'],
 (0, 1): ['v_1_1', 'v_0_1', 'v_0_0', 'v_0_2'],
 (0, 2): ['v_1_2', 'v_0_2', 'v_0_1', 'v_0_3'],
 (0, 3): ['v_1_3', 'v_0_3', 'v_0_2', 'v_0_3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get what you're looking for by just looping through your output.

```
groups = {}
for k in output.keys():
    v = output[k]
    if k[0] not in groups.keys():
        groups[k[0]] = []
    
    groups[k[0]].append(v)
```

Comment: why not just `for k,v in output.items():`?